# Ajax call not working on Firefox but working on Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, firefox

Here's the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: hostGlobal+"site/estrutura/ajax.php",
    contentType: "text/JSON",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
        action: "writeRequestStatus",
        status: 2,
        pedido_id: <?php echo $dadosPedido->id; ?>,
        fornecedor_id: <?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>,
        ids_produtos: ids
    },
    success:function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) { console.log(result); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**ids** is an array:

```
ids = [];
$(".top10").click(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
        var _checked = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
        ids.push(_checked);
    });
});
```

And here's **writeRequestStatus** on **hostGlobal+"site/estrutura/ajax.php"**:

```
if ($_POST["action"] == "writeRequestStatus") {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["ids_produtos"]); $i++) {
        _update("UPDATE tbl_pedidos_produtos SET status = ".$_POST["status"]." WHERE pedido_id = ".$_POST["pedido_id"]." AND id = ".$_POST["ids_produtos"][$i]);
        _update("UPDATE tbl_pedidos SET status_id = ".$_POST["status"]." WHERE id = ".$_POST["pedido_id"]);
        _update("UPDATE tbl_pedidos_fornecedors_produtos SET cotado = 1 WHERE pedido_id = ".$_POST["pedido_id"]." AND fornecedor_id = ".$_POST["fornecedor_id"]." AND produto_id = ".$_POST["ids_produtos"][$i]);
    }
}
```

The POST data copied by Firefox:

action=writeRequestStatus&status=2&pedido_id=1&fornecedor_id=110&ids_produtos%5B%5D=1

No error thrown, 200 OK, and it just does not work. The exact same call does work on Chrome and Opera, but on Firefox it does not.

EDIT:

Here's the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 14:42:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.14
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 3
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

By "does not work" I mean that that update call on MySQL does not work only on Firefox, for some obscure reason.

Comment: `No error thrown, 200 OK, and it just does not work.`. then it works. Can you see the server response to that request? In network tab, click in the request and open the Response tab.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: I asked for the document of the response, not the headers. However, you can debug the POST request in firefox with `var_dump($_POST)` or watching the server log in search for errors. Maybe you are sending bad fields like the `ids_produtos` array

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use prepared SQL statements.

Comment: Try upgrading to Firefox v49.0.2 and above , it will work.